# アセンブラ(NASM)のサブルーチンの書き方について

Tags: linux

x86環境でアセンブラ(NASM)の学習を始めています。
サブルーチンの書き方を学ぼうと思い、下部のコードを記載してみています。
期待している結果としては、

```
Hello, World
Japan
```

と、出力させたいのですが、下部のコードを実行すると、以下のように出力されます。

```
Hello, World
Japan
Japan
```

イメージとしては、17行目callでtestのサブルーチンを実行していることでJapanを出力させる処理を走らせていると思っているのですが、実際にはcallが無くても「test:」部を実行しているようです。
どのようにコーディングすればサブルーチンとしてのみ動作させられるでしょうか？

```
  1 section .data
  2 message db 'Hello, World', 0x0a
  3 message2 db 'Japan', 0x0a
  4
  5 length      equ $ -message
  6 length2         equ $ -message2
  7 section .text
  8 global _start
  9
 10 _start:
 11         mov     ecx, message
 12         mov     edx, length
 13         mov     eax, 4
 14         mov     ebx, 1
 15         int     0x80
 16
 17         call test
 18
 19         mov     eax, 1
 20         mov     ebx, 0 
 21         int     0x80
 22
 23         test:
 24                 mov     ecx, message2
 25                 mov     edx, length2
 26                 mov     eax, 4
 27                 mov     ebx, 1
 28                 int 0x80
 29                 ret
```

Answer (score 3):

あなたのコードのメインルーチンの最後には、

```
 19         mov     eax, 1
 20         mov     ebx, 0 
 21         int     0x80
```

と、sys_exitの呼び出しが含まれていますから、それを超えてサブルーチン`test`の部分が実行されてしまうことはないはずです。
(ebxに値を設定する必要はないように思うのですが、とりあえずあっても無害のはずです。)

Japanが2回表示される原因はこちらです。

```
  2 message db 'Hello, World', 0x0a
  3 message2 db 'Japan', 0x0a
  4
  5 length      equ $ -message
  6 length2         equ $ -message2
```

この定義ですと、`length`には`message`の最初から現在位置(`$`)までの長さを計算していることになりますから、その長さには`message2`というラベルを通り越して'Hello, World', 0x0a, 'Japan', 0x0aまで全部が含まれることになります。

```
 11         mov     ecx, message
 12         mov     edx, length
 13         mov     eax, 4
 14         mov     ebx, 1
 15         int     0x80
```

その結果、メインルーチンの上記処理を実行するとJapanの部分まで表示されることになります。

あなたの所望の動作をさせるには、先の2行目から6行目までを次のように書き直してください。

```
  2 message db 'Hello, World', 0x0a
  3 length      equ $ -message
  4
  5 message2 db 'Japan', 0x0a
  6 length2         equ $ -message2
```

これで`length`は'Hello, World', 0x0aの部分だけを表すようになります。

これから学習されるんなら64ビットコードの方が良いんじゃないかとか、`int 0x80`なんてのは古い書き方だとか、今時全部をアセンブラーで書くことはないから早めにCコンベンションのサブルーチンの書き方を覚えたほうが良いんじゃないかとか、いろいろ突っ込みどころはあるんですが、おいおい学習していってください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。提示頂いたコードで期待した動作となりました。アセンブラは学び始めたばかりで不明な箇所ばかりなので、これから学習を進めていければと思います